# Managing Shorcut and click Browser with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, shortcut

this case i use the latest version of mozilla firefox as my browser.

i want to disable all event click in my browser, then i want to change some shorcut browser on key board like F5, F6 etc.

This my code that i have

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('body').keypress(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if(e.which == 116) //for f5
                {
                    alert("ok"); //execute module
                }
                else if(e.which == 117) //for f6
                {
                    alert("ok");
                }
            });
            $('body').off("click"); //disable all click function
        });
</script>
```

untill I ask this question this code doesn't work, are there way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('body').off("click"); //disable all click function
```

Try

```
$('body *').off("click"); //disable all click function
```

But while using `.off()` just keep in mind that it only removes event handlers that were attached with `.on()`.

Comment: this work for event click in button tag but in input text still can click.

Comment: @newbie...i don't think `.click()` which we are disabling here is useful for text fields..generally we use `.keyup()`so try disabling that by using `$('body *').off("keyup");`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script for disabling right click using jquery. you can also add your own function when the right click triggered.

```
$('body').on('contextmenu', function(){
 //you can write your own code to display a menu
  return false;
});
```